# ldd says not found but .so file is in /usr/lib

Tags: linux, files

When I type `ldd` with my executable file there is one `not found` warning.

```
libCmp.so => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6ed7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6e6c000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6e48000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6d63000)
```

But this `so` file is in `/usr/lib`.
When I type `file libCmp.so`, I noticed that there is no `buildID` information in output.

```
libCmp.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

output of `file libgcc_s.so.1`

```
libgcc_s.so.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x6b7de7cba96b907b2961892b76c176b1ddbf4bee, stripped
```

Is this a problem ? and how can add this information to file ?

---

I tried to type `ldconfig -v |grep libCmp` in `/usr/lib`

```
/sbin/ldconfig: Path `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.13.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libCmp.so -> libCmp.so
```

But nothing change

Comment: Can you show us the command line used to link your executable?

Comment: also please show the output of "ls -la /usr/lib/libCmp*"

Comment: Did you find the lib?

Answer (score 4):

re-build the dynamic linker runtime bindings (as root):

```
ldconfig -v | grep libCmp
```

and it should
a) output your lib (meaning it was found)
b) correctly install needed symlinks, so the lib will be found in the future

a missing build-id is no problem.

Comment: I updated question

Answer (score 2):

If you have recently added libCmp.

As root you could try:

```
ldconfig -v
```

> ldconfig  creates  the  necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib and /usr/lib).  The cache is used by the run-time
>          linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so

The -v will make ldconfig list all the files it links in the cache. You could then you could view the output and confirm the presence of libCmp.

Comment: I updated question